# Terminating HTTPS on EC2 Instances Running Tomcat

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to enable HTTPS on my AWS EC2 instance that is being deployed using Elastic Beanstalk. The documentation to do this requires you to add [this snippet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html) in a directory `.ebextensions/https-instance.config` in the root directory of your app. I had to replace `certificate file contents` and `private key contents` with my certificate and key, respectively. I initially received an incorrect format error so I converted the snippet they provided to JSON and re-uploaded it -

```
{
  "files": {
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf": {
      "owner": "root",
      "content": "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so\nListen 443\n<VirtualHost *:443>\n  <Proxy *>\n    Order deny,allow\n    Allow from all\n  </Proxy>\n\n  SSLEngine             on\n  SSLCertificateFile    \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt\"\n  SSLCertificateKeyFile \"/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key\"\n  SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH\n  SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3\n  SSLHonorCipherOrder   On\n  \n  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security \"max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload\"\n  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY\n  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff\n  \n  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0\n  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/\n  ProxyPreserveHost on\n  \n</VirtualHost>\n",
      "group": "root",
      "mode": "000644"
    },
    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt": {
      "owner": "root",
      "content": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\ncertificate file contents\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
      "group": "root",
      "mode": "000400"
    },
    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key": {
      "owner": "root",
      "content": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate key contents # See note below.\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "group": "root",
      "mode": "000400"
    }
  },
  "container_commands": {
    "killhttpd": {
      "command": "killall httpd"
    },
    "waitforhttpddeath": {
      "command": "sleep 3"
    }
  },
  "packages": {
    "yum": {
      "mod_ssl": []
    }
  }
}
```

The deployment aborts with the error -

```
[Instance: i-0x012x0123x012xyz] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: httpd: no process found. container_command killhttpd in my-app-name/.ebextensions/https-instance.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I can tell that the error is being caused due to `container_commands` key which stops `httpd` after the configuration so that the new `https.conf` and certificate can be used. It tells me that it's trying to kill `httpd` but it can't find any such process running. `service httpd status` shows that `httpd.worker (pid 0123) is running` and I can also access my app online. `/var/log/eb-activity.log` also has nothing logged in it.

I've seen a few others post the same problem online but I could not find any solutions to it. Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you're using Elastic Beanstalk, any reason why you're not just terminating SSL at the ELB level?

Comment: @birryree I am but I want to terminate it all the way to the EC2 instance.

Comment: In that case, the problem may be that the `ebextensions` is trying to execute a `killall httpd`, but your process is called `httpd.worker`. What happens if you replace the `killall httpd` with `killall httpd.worker`?

Comment: @birryree That worked, thank you! My ELB health check is failing but the EB deployment was successful. I'll be really glad to accept your answer if you post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ebextensions` is trying to execute `killall httpd`, but your process is called `httpd.worker`.

Change the line in the `ebextensions` to be `killall httpd.worker`.

Comment: I get `Output: httpd: no process found` so I change it as you say, then I get `Output: httpd.worker: no process found`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Richard Are you running the exact same environment (Tomcat configuration on Elastic Beanstalk running Amazon Linux)? Do you have Apache HTTP Server enabled as the proxy in that case, or nginx? There are many configurations for which my advice doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I am `64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8`

Comment: @Richard - Sorry, was editing my comment when you answered - do you also have the Apache proxy settings enabled in your Elastic Beanstalk configuration? Or nginx instead? Or nothing?

Comment: I think I have nothing, I just followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html

Comment: What happens if I just remove the `killall` command? Or is that needed to get https working? (Excuse my ignorance).

Comment: @Richard - The `killall` is necessary because it causes (in this case) Apache to restart all its workers to pick up on the new SSL configuration. The configuration is applied on deployment to the server so the proxy needs to be restarted to recognize any custom changes you make. It sounds like you don't have apache configured, so you might have to [configure your Tomcast proxy server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-proxy

Comment: Thanks.  Will have a look

Comment: It says `The Tomcat platform uses Apache 2.2 for the proxy by default. You can choose to use nginx by including a configuration file in your source code`. Does that mean there should already be a proxy server? Does that mean there's something wrong with my environment?  Or should I add a `.ebextensions/nginx-proxy.config`? If my environment is okay, is it better to extend the `Default Apache Configuration` or `Default nginx Configuration`?

Comment: @Richard it does sound like Apache isn't configured in your environment - you might have to SSH into the machine to see. I personally don't use ElasticBeanstalk with Tomcat so at this point, I'm mostly shooting in the dark when it comes to anything Beanstalk-specific.

Comment: Thanks birryree, I think you have set me on the right path. I will do some investigation.

Comment: Hey Richard, were you finally able to get this working?